# Emailing professors in Japan

Tags: graduate-admissions, japan

I have started sending emails to professors in Tohoku University in japan to pursue my graduate studies in Medical Science. The following is the sample email which I am sending. I am a medical doctor and I don't have any undergraduate research experience. Can I get some opinion on how it sounds? Also should I make any modifications to increase my chances of getting responses? Thank you.

> Dear Professor “Professor's name",
>
> I hope this email finds you well. My name is Afsana Rahman. I have
> completed my Bachelor of Medicine and Bachelor of Surgery (MBBS) from
> Rangpur Medical College, Rajshahi University, with a first-class
> honours degree in Bangladesh in May 2018. I am very interested in
> developing my career in Medical research, which motivated me to pursue
> Graduate Studies in Medical Science at Tohoku University.
>
> My TOEFL iBT overall score is 103 out of 120. After completing my
> one-year internship training program at Rangpur Medical college in May
> 2019, I have been working as a Medical Officer in Rabeya Clinic and
> Nursing Home, Gaibandha, Bangladesh since September 2019. It is an
> independent healthcare establishment dedicated to providing
> comprehensive healthcare within a vast area of North Bengal. I am also
> working as a Lecturer at North Bengal Medical Assistant Training
> School in Gaibandha, Bangladesh since December 2019.
>
> I have been through your website and studied details on your research
> topics and publications. Your research theme on new drug delivery
> system for retinal disease by developing deployment type nanosheets
> creation technology for sustained long-term drug administration to the
> retina has struck me as revolutionary and inspiring. As my future goal
> is to be a cutting-edge researcher in this field, it would be a great
> honor if you kindly consider me in your research group and provide me
> the opportunity to enhance my potential under your guidance.
>
> I have attached my Curriculum Vitae and Academic transcripts for your
> kind consideration. I will be at your disposal if you need any kind of
> detailed information. Please let me know if any opportunity is present
> for me.
>
> Sincerely Yours, Afsana Rahman, MBBS (Rajshahi University),
> Bangladesh.

Comment: Have you read this question and the corresponding answers? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119787/how-to-ask-via-email-for-supervision-of-professor-for-japan-graduate-program-adm?rq=1 I think there are some very useful tips in there that would answer your question, do you agree?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you read in detail their application guidelines in the university's website? (https://www.med.tohoku.ac.jp/english/admissions/admissions/apply/) It would be frustrating to send an email, and later find out that you couldn't be accepted because of some minor issue. Also, it is debatable whether you should include attached files in your first email, because  it might be misidentified as spam. I'm not sure what is best, but in your first attempt, you might ask "Please let me know if I can send you my CV and Academic Transcripts for you to evaluate".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x)

Comment: @Jeroen thank you, I found some really useful tips there.

Comment: @djohn thank you for the advice, I have checked their website, apparently, they have completed their qualification prescreening for 2022. I am not sure if I should send emails for 2022 admission now.

Comment: @enthu Thank you. I have checked the link. It was helpful.

Comment: @afsana rahman It is better to send emails to professors in early or mid-January, because right now all of the university staff is going to be busy evaluating the applications. In the meantime, during this month and December I advise you to prepare all of the application documents beforehand, and to read carefully all of the application guidelines. Check if you need to get any certificates from your previous academic institutions (ex: GPA certificates, diplomas, etc.).

Comment: @afsana rahman If you do need to get certificates,, the next two months are the best time to obtain such documents (if possible, try to 3 copies of each certificate, you might need them in the future). Use your computer to prepare the application papers for your two most desired universities. Even if you get accepted by a professor from a different university, you can always copy-paste the contents of your previous applications into the application papers of another university. In Japan, you always need to prepare for everything way before the deadline, otherwise you might get into trouble.

Comment: @djohn so I have to start emailing professors in the January of the year before the one I want to get an admission, right? I mean if I want admission in 2023, I have to start sending emails in January 2022.

Comment: @afsana rahman it is possible to send emails later than January, and I know some colleagues who were successful in getting accepted by advisors 6 months, or even 2 months before the application deadline. However, the longer you wait, the more difficult it will be to get an advisor to accept you . Each advisor can only accept a limited number of students, and students compete for the most reputed advisors in the best universities, so the ones who contact first will have an advantage. But if you still have a chance to apply for the 2022 year, there is no harm in trying, you might get lucky.